# Implement HTML Entity Decode in react.js

Tags: reactjs, html-entities

I am outputting the text using API from the server, and  I have an admin which has the html fields for facilitating filling the content. The issue in here that now the text displaying with html codes. How I can get rid of that undeeded html codes. I guess I have to use html entity decode? How I will implement that in react project? Below you see that the text illustrates not only text and html code.

[image]

```
  export  class FullInfoMedia extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const renderHTML = (escapedHTML: string) => React.createElement("div", { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: escapedHTML } });

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="about-title">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <img className="center-block" src={this.props.about.image}/>

                            <h2>{this.props.about.title}</h2>
                            {renderHTML(<p>{this.props.about.body}</p>)} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but be sure you render only your input, not users. It can be great way to XSS.

Example of using:

```
const renderHTML = (rawHTML: string) => React.createElement("div", { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: rawHTML } });
```

And then in a component:

```
{renderHTML("<p>&amp;nbsp;</p>")}
```

Comment: so, for example the code should look like that the code in above. I just added, pls could u review

Comment: but now it renders only word "[object Object]"

Comment: Input to the renderHTML function has to be string, not an object. You are calling `<p>...</p>`, but you need to call `"<p>...</p>"` (with quotes).

Comment: for me worked this code  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.about.body}}

Comment: I suppose your `this.props.about.body`is string, so simply `{renderHTML(this.props.about.body)}` is what you should use. If your props is not a string, you need to convert it.

Comment: @Feruza if the answer is correct, please consider marking it as Accepted

Comment: Even though this might seem like a good idea, still not enough as this could lead to potential XSS issues. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57480647/4229159), to see how to overcome those.

Comment: You're a life saver!

Answer (score 11):

Even though you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` it's not really a good practice, and as stated by [Marek Dorda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7499741/marek-dorda) it's a great thing for making your app XSS vulnerable.

A better solution would be to use the `he` library. https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

This would be an example of how would your component look with it.

```
import he from 'he'

export class FullInfoMedia extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const renderHTML = (escapedHTML: string) => React.createElement("div", { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: escapedHTML } });

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="about-title">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <img className="center-block" src={this.props.about.image}/>
                            <h2>{this.props.about.title}</h2>
                            { he.decode(this.props.about.body) }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Also, if it were my codebase, I would most likely move the decoding to the API call, and in the component just consume the value that comes from the store

Answer (score 3):

You can simply try this, it decodes text and then display.

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:"&amp;nbsp;"}}/>
```