# &amp; showing in WP categories name, why?

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, api

I'm using the Wordpress REST-API and I'm having issues with the **&** character. I've got a custom post type and using wordpress built in categories for it. One of the categories uses the **&** sign.

For some reason it's showing as `&amp;` in the JSON data I get... and therefor also on my front end.

I tried looking for a solution but couldn't find any or figure out why. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

That's because it has to be encoded to be sent safely. It's not only `&`, but there are also several other [reserved characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455639/3880373). On your end, after you get the JSON you can decode it like so:

`html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually using react as my front-end, how would I encode that using react? Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361689/implement-html-entity-decode-in-react-js

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using 'he' package to decode my JSON.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing post, instead of `&` you can write `&amp;` there and it will be translated to & without any problems.

Also you could use the str_replace function to convert that to `&amp;` eg:

```
$new_text = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $your_string);
```